# What if one family member doesn't have a photo ID for domestic air travel in India?

Tags: air-travel, india, identity-cards, domestic-travel

My friend has booked tickets for vacation in India (domestic travel), but realized that his wife doesn't have any photo ID. 
Will any of the following documents work for his wife?

1. Marriage certificate
2. Nationalized bank's passbook ([Corporation Bank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation_Bank))

Their travel date is next week, so there is less time to apply for any photo ID like PAN card/Passport.

Comment: what happened in the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Air India mentions in their [Citizen's Charter](http://www.airindia.com/Images/pdf/Citizen%27s_charter_updated_13th_Jun.pdf),

> For domestic journeys, along with a copy of your ticket, you will be required to show any of the following identification:
>
> Photo Identification of the passenger i.e. : **Passport, Driving License, Pan Card, Voter card ,Student ID, Military ID, Photo Credit Card, Airlines ID, Any Photo ID card by Airline, Any other photo card issued by Government agencies**.

[Jet Airways](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/TermsAndConditions/KioskCheckin.aspx) also provides similar information,

> It is mandatory to produce a valid photo identification using the Kiosk check-in boarding pass for security clearance as well as for boarding. A valid photo identification could be an official Government issued photo identification, a driving license, an election photo identification, Passport (for international guests), or a photo credit card

What I infer from this is as long as you have any official documentation from the government or from the airline or a credit card with a photograph, this would be considered a valid photo ID.

As far as I can understand the Marriage Certificate should be acceptable on grounds of being a photo identification issued by a Government agency, but there is no guarantee of this because Air India mentions *Photo Card* whereas Jet Airways doesn't mention this at all. **I would suggest you to use either a Voter ID or Aadhar Card**.

Comment: @jaczjill No problem at all! Have a safe trip!