# Is a student ID issued by the Central Board of Secondary Education, New Delhi valid for boarding on a domestic flight within India?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, paperwork, identity-cards, domestic-travel

I am a student and will be traveling on an upcoming domestic trip on 20 October 2014 within India. This is my first trip and I am 17 years old. Since I am only 17, I am not eligible to obtain government identity proofs such as voter id or a driving license.

However, I do possess an identity card issued by Central Board of Secondary Education (C.B.S.E), New Delhi, (which is a government body) for 10th standard senior secondary board examination at national level. I can use the same ID card for a train journey. The ID card states my name, my father's name, my date of birth and contains a colored photograph of me.

I want to know if that will be valid for boarding on a domestic flight.

Comment: Do you have an Aadhar card? See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34966/what-if-one-family-member-doesnt-have-a-photo-id-for-domestic-air-travel-in-ind/34970#34970

Comment: No sir. I only have this one. Besides I have class 10 cbse marks sheet, school id, fiitjee contract statement, fiitjee id card. All of them contain my photo and name.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned on the answer to [What if one family member doesn't have a photo ID for domestic air travel in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34966/what-if-one-family-member-doesnt-have-a-photo-id-for-domestic-air-travel-in-ind/34970#34970),

According to the airlines charters for Air India and Jet Airways, as long as you have a government issued photo ID (CBSE will be included in this case as it is on of the major Central Boards for education in India), you should be able to board the flight by using it as a photo ID.

In addition to this, your class 10th CBSE passing certificate (I believe it does have a picture on it) will be a very good idea to carry with you and should be a valid form of ID as well.