# ID Document for Unaccompanied Minor in Indian Domestic Flight

Tags: india, paperwork, minors, domestic-travel

Do CISF and various Indian airlines accept ID cards issued to students by their schools (a private school, in this case) as a "valid photo ID" card? The child will be an unaccompanied minor with no other ID document available (they also have an Aadhaar number but not the original card sent by UIDAI at the time of signup. I have read mixed reports about the acceptance of the e-Aadhaar printout).

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [Q, whether a student id is sufficient](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35948/is-a-student-id-issued-by-the-central-board-of-secondary-education-new-delhi-va/36053#36053)

Comment: Perhaps related; but that answer talks about CBSE-issued ID cards. As far as I know CBSE does not issue ID cards to students; it is the individual schools that do that. Also CBSE is a government agency and I was talking of CISCE which is a private body; so even if they issued ID cards they wouldn't conform to "government issued ID cards".

Comment: I'm still looking; on what airline will they fly and what age are they? I did see that an electronic version of Aadhaar may be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Air India has this page:

http://www.airindia.in/documents-to-carry.htm

Which says that school ID cards are fine for children. I found similar language in many other airlines' websites (eg: Air Asia - http://www.airasia.com/in/en/about-us/terms-and-conditions-i5.page). Seems like school ID cards are fine in India for domestic travel.